# Circular Bar Graph

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, graph

[image]

One of the app I'm using has bar graph in circular shape. I've tried to create this by using UIBezierPath with arcCenter but I felt like this is completely wrong approach.

The code I'm currently using:

```
func drawGraph(){
        var startDegrees = 120

    for _ in 0...10{
        let startAngle: CGFloat = radians(of: startDegrees)
        let endAngle: CGFloat = radians(of: startDegrees + 5)

        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = min(center.x, center.y) - trackBorderWidth / 2 - CGFloat(Int.random(in: 10...50))

        let trackPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        trackPath.lineWidth = trackBorderWidth
        trackPath.lineCapStyle = .square

        trackBackgroundColor.set()
        trackPath.stroke()

        startDegrees += 7
    }
}
```

Do you have better solutions or do you know any similar graph libraries like this?

EDIT:

So I've been trying to change my code little bit, I'm able to create something similar with this code:

```
func drawGraph(){
        var temp:CGFloat = 120.0

    for i in 0...64{
        let startAngle: CGFloat = radians(of: temp)
        let endAngle: CGFloat = radians(of: temp + 5)
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = min(center.x, center.y) - trackBorderWidth / 2 - 10

        let randomNumber = CGFloat(Int.random(in: 10...20))
        let trackPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius + randomNumber / 2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        trackPath.lineWidth = randomNumber
        trackPath.lineCapStyle = .butt

        UIColor.randomColor().set()
        trackPath.stroke()

        temp += 5.5
    }

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: 101, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a condition for bar's height and fade? Or this is the static UI and will remains the same?

Comment: @SharadChauhan bar height will be dynamic but it'll scale itself for the data's value. For example for the highest value it'll be 20 and it'll calculate height for other values.